# UnicodeDecodeError while upgrading from 20.04.02 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I was trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 using the GUI update-manager tool. But it kept crashing after the 1st step only. So I tried to upgrade via CLI, by running the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. But I am getting the below error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                 
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,267 kB]                                                                                                                        
Fetched 1,268 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                       
authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'jammy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                           
Hit http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                              
Hit https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                               
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/swi-prolog/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                
Hit http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                                                                                             
Fetched 114 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1873, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 906, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 99, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 122, in jammyPostInitialUpdate
    self._test_and_fail_on_pam_tally()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 395, in _test_and_fail_on_pam_tally
    content = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 16: invalid continuation byte
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1873, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 906, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 99, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 122, in jammyPostInitialUpdate
    self._test_and_fail_on_pam_tally()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nd8my0mh/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 395, in _test_and_fail_on_pam_tally
    content = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 16: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried each and every answer I found on the internet, but no luck :(. Please help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1986429/comments/2) with a manual.

> File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l3yamuwr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 395, in _test_and_fail_on_pam_tally
>
> This is the upgrader script that was running when the error was thrown. Edit that file (as root) and go to line 395 and see that you're in a "for" loop:
>
> ```
>    for f in os.listdir('/etc/pam.d'):
>        if f in ('common-account', 'common-auth', 'common-password',
>                 'common-session', 'common-session-noninteractive'):
>            # managed by pam-auth-updates, and any references to
>            # pam_tally* will be handled by libpam-modules on upgrade
>            # without breaking
>            continue
>        with open(os.path.join('/etc/pam.d', f)) as f:
>            content = f.read()
>            if re.search('^[^#]*pam_tally', content, re.MULTILINE): <--- >line 395
>        <snipped>
> ```
>
> The script is looping through files in /etc/pam.d. You can go look there for >the trouble, or you can edit the script to find which file is being processed >when the error is thrown. Like this:
>
> ```
>     with open(os.path.join('/etc/pam.d', f)) as f:
>         for f in os.listdir('/etc/pam.d'):
>             print ("Rob says: " + f)
>         content = f.read()
> ```
>
> Now run the upgrader again from this temporary directory, which includes the >edits made above. Like this:
>
> sudo /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-l3yamuwr/DistUpgrade/jammy

Comment: Running this `sudo /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader/DistUpgrade/jammy` resulted in another error `No view can be imported, aborting`.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a binary file in your /etc/pam.d directory. A tar or other such package file is a common culprit for this error.

Answer (score 0):

the unicode decode errors aren't central. Underlying the error apt or dpkg fails on package dependencies. The package names can give you a hint for what it can't resolve. Look for apt error message lines below.

I myself ran into it for libc:i386, dependency to libgcc-s1:i386. On a machine that didn't need i386 packages or had marked installed i386 arch packages.

Removing residual `*_i386.deb` from `/var/cache/apt/archives` let dpkg continue. You can have an altogether different dependency issue.